# How does LIGO account for curvature of Earth?

Tags: experimental-physics, spacetime, curvature, gravitational-waves, ligo

Using an earth curvature calculator, I found that at a distance of 4 km (the length of LIGO's arms), more 1.26 m is hidden by the horizon. When constructing LIGO, did they account for the curvature of the Earth to allow the beam to travel in a straight line?

Comment: Figure it this way: the suspended mirrors at the ends of the arms are (IIRC) about 40 cm in diameter. If they hadn't considered the matter the machine wouldn't work.

Comment: Indeed. The 4 feet of difference over 4 kilometers isn't exactly an engineering challenge compared with building the tunnel in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is yes, the earth's curvature was factored into the LIGO design. Read the LIGO wbpages, [here](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/vacuum),

> LIGO’s arms are long enough that the curvature of the Earth itself was a complicating factor when installing the vacuum tubes. It wasn’t enough for LIGO’s civil engineers to smooth a level path and assemble each arm’s tubes in a straight line. To ensure a perfectly flat, straight, and level beam path, the Earth’s curvature (more than a vertical meter over each 4 km arm) was countered by GPS-assisted earth-moving and high-precision concrete work.

and [here](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/facts)

> Curvature of the Earth:  LIGO’s arms are so long that the curvature of the Earth is a measurable 1 meter (vertical) over the 4 km length of each arm. The most precise concrete pouring and leveling imaginable was required to counteract this curvature and ensure that LIGO’s vacuum chambers were truly "flat" and level. Without this work, LIGO's lasers would hit the end of each arm 1 m above the mirrors it is supposed to bounce off of!

Answer (score 0):

The canal next to the arms of ligo would prove or disprove curvature of the earth, as we know water curves and over the distance of two and a half miles the end of the arm would be a meter higher above the water level.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/395358)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).